# Adding rows in a NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a tableView and two buttons. One to add a row, and one to remove a row(selected).

1. How would I add a row of textbox cells?
2. Also, how would i remove the selected row?
3. Would it be possible for the user to select a row, not just individual cells?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for Mac OSX :

You can use two ways, in both the cases you deal with the model not the view  : [ArrayController](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5462248/arraycontrollersortsearch-zip-58k?da=y) using [Binding](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php) and Conventional Programming.

> 1 How would I add a row of textbox cells?

```
//in the IBAction of add button
[yourModelArray addObject:newObject];
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

> 2 Also, how would i remove the selected row?

```
//in the IBAction of remove button
[yourModelArray removeObjectAtIndex:[yourTableView selectedRow];
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

> 3 Would it be possible for the user to select a row, not just individual cells?

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[yourTableview selectRowIndexes:indexSet byExtendingSelection:NO];
//If you want to select multiple rows, use YES.
```